# What is the drawback if two same objects have different hashcode

Tags: java, oop

I know that different objects may have same hash code. But what if equal objects have different hashcode (just a curious question so don't ask me why i do so):

```
public class Myclass{
    int data = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof  Myclass && ((Myclass) obj).data == this.data;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)(Math.random()*1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will not be albe to use your object properly in HashSet or as keys in HashMap.

Comment: @Pshemo - Assume two instances of a class, say obj1 and obj2, such that obj1.equals(obj2) returns true but obj1.hashCode() != obj2.hashCode(). Would you pls explain how this pose problem in using them in HashSet/map?

Comment: @KGhatak Purpose of set is to store unique elements using result of `equals()` method for uniqueness check. So if two objects are equal we shouldn't be able to place both of them in set (same about map keys). HashSet is fast because stores its elements in "buckets" which hold elements with *similar* hashcodes. This way set can use `obj.hascode()` to locate bucket which it should search for potential duplicate (it skips other buckets which speeds things up).

Comment: @KGhatak Now lets say we placed `obj1` in bucket X, but hash of `obj2` points to bucket Y. While inserting `obj2` because of its hash set will search only bucket Y for duplicates, so obj1 will not be tested for equality because it is in different bucket. This will allow to add `obj2` to set even if it already holds `obj1`. So we ended up with set holding duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fail to satisfy equals-hashCode contract, then any algorithm or data structure which relies on this contract may work incorrectly. The examples of such data structures are `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `Hashtable` (if your object is used as key), `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`.

Note that in your case the problem is even worse: you return different hashCode on the same object when `hashCode` method is invoked several times. So you don't even need two equal objects to break the collection. For example, such code usually prints false (though may occasionally print true):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass m = new Myclass();
    Set<Myclass> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(m);
    System.out.println(set.contains(m));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have in your code is not two equal objects with different hashcode, but an object that will return different hashcode on each invocation of `hashcode()`.

What will happen is that you wont be able to use this class in hashes- since you'll get different hashcode each time, you wont be able to get your object out from the hash, and also everytime you insert into the hash an object, it will be treated as non-existing in the hash

Answer (score -1):

Hashcode is used in datastructures like  HashMap or HashSet to determine where a particular object is going to be stored at. If two objects end up with the same hash code, then it results in a confusion when they are to be stored or retrieved from hash based structures.

Comment: That's not what he asked.